# Drop down menu hover does not cover whole text

Tags: html, css, markup

**Screenshot1:**

[image]

**Screenshot 2:**

[image]

If you look at the screenshot1, you can see when you hover over web design it doesn't completely change the background color. However it does in case you hover over text 'Search Engine' in Screenshot 2. 
Here is the markup:
**Html:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" >My Health</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#" >Fitness</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Diet &amp; Nutrition</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search engine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Stress Management</a></li>                          
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    background: url('../images/nav-bg.png') repeat;
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
    }
    #nav ul li a{
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font: bold 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 9px 14px;
        }
        #nav ul li a:hover{
            color: #355da5;
            background: #fff;
            border: medium black;
            }
            #nav ul li ul{
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 130px;
                margin: 8px 0px 0px 180px;
                background: url('../images/nav-bg.png') repeat;
                }                               
                #nav ul li ul li a{
                    text-align: center;                 
                    font-size: 12px;
                    }
                #nav ul li:hover ul, li.over ul{
                    display: block;                 
                    }
```

Does anyone know how can i fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your nested <a> tags are matched by the css selector `#nav ul li a`, and are therefore floated left.

try adding `float:none;` inside `#nav ul li ul li a`

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `width: 100%` on `#nav ul li a`.

Comment: +1 - This fiddle will show you what is wrong. Links are not block level elements. This means they shrink to fit their content. By giving an explicit 100% width they will now fill their container. Add width: 100% to `#nav ul li ul li a` to see the fix. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/uubHs/

Comment: it ended up giving me some weird result.